# title too long when using amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

I am going to submit an artcile to a conference, and it requires the authours to use amsart document class. When I use this class, on the top of each page, it shows the title or authros name(and Institut). My article has a long title, but it is fine in the first page. But from 2nd page to the end, the title shown on the top is too long to fit in a page width.
I am not going to drop these titles, since it requires the authous not to change the style. But if I can use a shorter title to be shown on the top of each page, but keep the original title to be shown on the first page, it would be good. Someone had the same problem before? And how you deal with it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `amsart` class provides an optional argument to `\title`:

```
\title[Short title]{Possibly very long title}
```

Comment: Is this only a feature of `amsart` or do other standard classes support this as well?

Comment: This is a feature of `amsart`; `article` doesn't have it, not sure about `scrartcl`. Consult the documentation of the class.

Comment: thats the sweetness

Comment: This solution still works for the 2017 ACM SigConf template

Answer (score 6):

If you really don't want to shorten your title, and it's only slightly too long, you can do as follows:

`\title[\resizebox{4.5in}{!}{Long title}]{Long title}`

Comment: Is there a way to break long title into several lines in header?

Answer (score 1):

You might also try redefining the `\shorttitle` command, just like the list of authors is also shortened in the headers of the sample file:

```
% The default list of authors is too long for headers}
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{B. Trovato et al.}
\renewcommand{\shorttitle}{Your short title}
```

Comment: This seems to be an alternative method to access the same variable as the optional argument to `\title` (potentially overwriting any short title set with `\title[Foo]{Foo bar}`).