# Manually control the header in article

Tags: header-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [title too long when using amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44510/title-too-long-when-using-amsart)

Minimal working example (LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\author{AUTHOR}
\title{REALLY LONG TITLE}

\maketitle

Body of the article

\end{document}
```

So on even pages, there is the name of author (plus the number of page in the left corner).
On odd pages, there is this really long title which does not fit. I would like to manually control it: to tell the program to write some SHORT TITLE as an odd-page header.

Could you please write down a complete correct version, because I am not a TeX expert.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you, this is so simple... I didn't see the duplicate, sorry about this.