# Put different title on the top of pages

Tags: titles, frame-title, titling

I am writing a paper. Since, my title is too long, i need to write short title for top pages. For instance, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04499.pdf) has a long title, but title of top pages are different. Does one help me ?

I have another question. How can one put a title from some page to other page, and then put another title from some page to end?

So here is a demo:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
%\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[lem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[lem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[lem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem{fact}[lem]{Fact}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[lem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[lem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem*{notat}{Notation}



\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}


\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb C} 

\newcommand{\clC}{\widehat \C}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}

\newcommand{\bd}{\partial}

\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
%opening
%opening
\title{EQUILIBRIUM STATES OF GENERALISED SINGULARVALUE POTENTIALS AND APPLICATIONS TO AFFINEITERATED FUNCTION SYSTEMS}

\address{}
\date{}
\email{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! We can help, but we need a minimal, compilable, (non)working example

Comment: @Bernard : I don't know how i can make it like Tex form.

Comment: @RR: Use `\title[<shortened title>]{<long title>}` to specify the shortened form of the title that will be displayed in the page headers.

Comment: Related: [title too long when using amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44510/134144)

Comment: @leandriis : Thanks. It works. Do you know my second question?

Comment: @leandriis : Short title cover the number of pages.

Comment: @RR: If the short title overlaps with the page number, your short title is still too  long for the available space in the header.

Comment: Regarding "How can one put a title from some page to other page, and then put another title from some page to end?": Why should the title of a paper change within the paper?

Comment: @leandriis : Because my paper has two parts. I'm wondering maybe putting two titles are good idea.

Comment: If you think you're doing your readers a service by creating two separate "short titles" -- the second being "applications to affine iterated function systems", right? -- in the header line of each page, I'm afraid your expectations regarding your readers' attention span are utterly unrealistic. From experience, I'd say that ca. 99% of readers do *not* play close attention the running headers, and these readers would be highly unlikely to notice the change in the "short title". Either use a *single* "short title" for the entire document or write two separate standalone documents.

Comment: I'd go for `\title[Equilibrium states of generalised singular value potentials]{Equilibrium states of generalised singular value potentials, with applications to affine iterated function systems}`. Note the almost-complete absence of UPPERCASE LETTERS.

Comment: @Mico `amsart` prints title and subtitle uppercase anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose a short title:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{showkeys,lipsum} % remove for production version

%\usepackage{scalefnt} % what for?
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\floatplacement{figure}{H} % this is sure to ruin pagination

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[lem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[lem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[lem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem{fact}[lem]{Fact}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[lem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[lem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem*{notat}{Notation}



\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}


\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} % \renewcommand?

\newcommand{\clC}{\widehat{\C}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\newcommand{\bd}{\partial}

\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

%opening

\title[Equilibrium states of generalised singular value potentials]
  {Equilibrium states of generalised singular value potentials, 
   with applications to affine iterated function systems}

\address{}
\date{}
\email{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

I added also a few modifications. Beware that `\floatplacement{H}` is a very dangerous thing to do, because it will most certainly make pagination impossible.

Also `heightrounded` for `geometry` is important, in order to avoid warnings on every page (the first page will *always* issue a warning with `amsart`.

[image]